# Position Vue chip on html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am new to front-end development. I am using Vue JS to position v-chip on the canvas (explained with an image below).

[image: UI]

I have written code to drag and drop the chip on the canvas. But the chip always go to the top-left position (image is shown below).
[image: After drag and drop chip goes to top-left position]

Below is my code of the drop function, which handles the drop,

```js
drop: function (ev) {
     
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        var chip = document.getElementById(data);

        ev.target.appendChild(chip);
        chip.style.x = ev.clientX;
        chip.style.y = ev.clientY;
        //chip.style.top = ev.clientX;
        //chip.style.left = ev.clientY;

    }
```

I tried changing 'style' of v-chip by changing x, y, top, and left but I am not able to position it to specific location where user dropped the chip on the canvas. I am not sure what is the right way to do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try `console.log( chip.style.x)` before assigning value and give me the output

Comment: Hi @boussadjrabrahim, before assigning value, chip.style.x is empty.

Comment: empty or undefined? i need the exact value before assigning it

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim, it is empty. You can see it here: https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=5eb6db2d33bb40ddaa6331fe327f3049

Comment: Instead of `var chip = document.getElementById(data);` try `var chip = document.querySelector("#"+data);`

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim, it is still empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181035/discussion-between-mrp-and-boussadjra-brahim).